# Lucene 6.2.1 taking more cpu cycles while indexing

Tags: lucene, freebsd

[image]We have migrated from lucene 2.4.1 to lucene 6.2.1 and observed that CPU is spiking comparatively high as compared to lucene 2.4.1 while indexing data. For ~1.3 million records(one line - max 40 characters) CPU is spiking upto 70% whereas in lucene 2.4.1 it is only 9.26%. The machine being used has 6 cores(its physical device(unix system) not VM )

Through the profiler(Visual VM) we see that fsync utility is taking more CPU cycles.(suspecting the cause of high CPU not sure though)

Any pointers to overcome the issue? Is the behavior expected in lucene 6.2.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fsync is a blocking operation and does not use CPU but waits for IO to complete. The Profiler only measures time, not cpu usage.

lucene 2.4 is very old, a lot has changed. For example compression is on per default, which alone could already explain the higher CPU usage.

CPU utilization also does not mean anything, it just means the CPU is not waiting for something else - which is a good thing. You should look how long it takes to index your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see the screen shot attached.

Comment: @Abhishek i think you misunderstand what a profiler/sampler does. fsync is waiting for the kernel to write something to the disk. no cpu is used there.